Listings produces 'misplaced \noalign' when including a LaTeX array
The following MWE demonstrates how valid LaTeX code produces a Misplaced \noalign error when the LaTeX code is to be displayed with listings. How can this be fixed?
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{LaTeXstyle}{
  language=[LaTeX]{TeX}}

\newcommand*{\LaTeXcode}{\lstinline[
  basicstyle=\upshape\ttfamily,
  style=LaTeXstyle]}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{cc}\hline \text{Model} & \text{Value} \\ \hline 1 & 1.2 \\ 2 & 2.4\\ \hline \end{array}\] % works

\LaTeXcode{\[\begin{array}{cc}\hline \text{Model} & \text{Value} \\ \hline 1 & 1.2 \\ 2 & 2.4\\ \hline \end{array}\]} % doesn't work (throws ./MWE.tex:17: Misplaced \noalign.)

\end{document}


\lstinline is supposed to be used with delimiters like \verb: \lstinline[options]!stuff! for example not {stuff}.

Pretty much duplicate of errors - Can't escape curly braces in \lstinline - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange

As mentioned by others \LaTeXcode!FooBar! works, \LaTeXcode{...} does not always

Wow, thanks a lot, I didn't see that one. So I guess {} cannot be used because that's part of the language.

Ugh, you got it completely wrong. The problem is listings package does not handle {...{...}...} (it stops at the first }!) and currently there's no way to escape it except using another character. Read carefully the linked answer: The first } ends the argument.
